# Does the existence of a derived class modify a base class, even if the derived class is never used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, polymorphism

I have a base class, `Sample` and a derived class `SignalSample`, and the code for both of these classes normally resides within the same file `Sample.py`.

I import these classes into my main script in the usual way: `from Sample import Sample, SignalSample`

While chasing down a bug within one of these classes, I noticed some unusual behavior: deleting the code for the `SignalSample` derived class changed the behavior of the `Signal` base class.

So my question is, can the existence of a derived class alter a base class, even if the derived class is never instantiated?

To be concrete,  I tried the following combinations.

1. The code for `Sample` and `SignalSample`  are both in `Sample.py`. `from Sample import Sample, SignalSample` is used in my main script to load these classes. `Sample`  objects are instantiated, there are no `SignalSample` objects instantiated, the code is just there and unused. In this scenario, I get an error which I will call "type 1".
2. Delete the code for `SignalSample` inside `Sample.py`, and remove the  `... import SignalSample` statement. In this case, I get a different error which I'll call  "type 2".

Note that I don't think the errors are coming from the classes themselves (although they may be), it was more that  I found it interesting that the behavior of the code seemed to change because there was an inherited class, even though that class was not used.

This is a stripped-down example of my setup, note that this is not an MWE of the source of my bug, as at the moment I don't know where it is coming from, and so I can't even narrow it down. It's not the solution to the bug I'm looking for, just more information on this seemingly strange behavior of class inheritance.

```
# file Sample.py
class Sample:
   def __init__(self):
      self._tfile = None
      self._filepath = None

   def calculate_filepath(self):
      return "my/file/path"

   __calculate_filepath = calculate_filepath # private copy

   def get_histogram(self, histogram_name):
      if not self._filepath:
         self._filepath = self.calculate_filepath()
      if not self._tfile:
         from ROOT import TFile # this is a special filetype 
         self._tfile = TFile.Open(self._filepath, "READ")

      histo = self._tfile.Get(histogram_name)
      histo.SetDirectory(0)
      self._tfile.Close()
      return histo

class SignalSample(Sample):
   def __init__(self):

      # Inherit
      Sample.__init__(self)

      self._filepath = self.calculate_filepath()

   def calculate_filepath(self):
      # Overloaded version of the function in Sample
      return "my/very/special/filepath"
```

Note that I chose to call the `calculate_filepath` method inside `get_histogram` because I wanted to avoid possible namespace clashes with the derived class. This is also why I try to make the method "private" with the namespace mangling. This is also why I open the special `TFile` file inside the `get_histogram` method, although it is nice that I can then also `Close` this file inside the same function. Perhaps this isn't the correct usage and maybe this related to the source of my problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If that's not a [mre] what is it trying to show?

Comment: @jonrsharpe all I want to know is, if you write the code for a derived class, does that code affect the behavior of the base class, even if derived-class objects are never instantiated?

Comment: It certainly *can* do. For example, even if you never instantiate the subclass it will appear in the parent class's `__subclasses__()` list, so if there's behaviour based on that it will change.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that @jonrsharpe. Are there ways the `__subclasses__()` list be accessed without explicitly calling it? The methods in the example I show above show the basic structure of my classes, I don't understand how that could affect the base class?

Comment: That was just one example, the point is that: yes, there are ways that it can. As to the problem in your specific circumstances, you'll have to give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

`get_histogram` looks potentially broken if it is called more than once. You assign the opened file to the instance (on `self._tfile`), but then close it before returning... that means that next time the method is called `not self._tfile` will probably (*) evaluate to `False`, meaning that you then try to call `Get` on a closed file. If you are using a sane library this would probably throw a nice error telling you this, but I see you're using ROOT so who knows what might happen :)

Probably simplest would be *not* to store the file on `Sample`, and just open the file whenever `get_histogram` is called?

(*) Implicit booliness is sometimes worth avoiding. In particular when what you *actually* want to check is whether something is None, prefer writing `if x is None:`  ( https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations )

Incidentally, in this example, `__calculate_filepath = calculate_filepath # private copy` isn't doing anything, since you never actually use it.

Comment: Thanks @tom, file is no longer stored in `Sample` (although in practise it was only called once per lifetime of each Sample object). I also removed the `__calculate_filepath` variable as you suggest. Unfortunately I still observe different behaviour in my code depending on whether of not I add the `import SignalSample`. Perhaps this would require a fuller example ...

Comment: I think so. As @jonrsharpe observed above, it is certainly *possible* to do all kinds of hideously disgusting things in Python. If `Sample` were to inherit from a root class - or declare its existence to ROOT in any fashion - then I think the probability of nefarious play is somewhat higher.